# Start Windows GUI program in the PuTTY shell

Tags: putty

I created an SSH session into my localhost through PuTTY. I am running OpenBSD server on the localhost which is a Windows 7 machine. The login was successful. Now I want to start programs in the PuTTY shell for example `notepad.exe`. I changed the directory to `c:\windows\system32`. The command `start notepad` runs without error but I don't see any window.

Is the notepad running in the background without a windows. If yes, how to make the window visible??

Comment: *"running OpenBSD server"*: Is it virtual machine? Or how do you run OpenBSD server of Windows 7?

Comment: Your question would better fit on [su]. It's not really [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: "*OpenBSD server on the localhost which is a Windows 7*" doesn't make sense. How can you run two OpenBSD **and** Windows 7 at the same time. And I'm pretty sure there is no `notepad.exe` on OpenBSD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite likely the Notepad is run in an invisible Windows session on the server. Note that it does not make a difference in this case that the server is the local machine.

If you hoped for the window to appear on the "local" machine magically, you are out of luck.

Generally, it's possible to run a GUI application on remote machine and see the GUI locally. On Unix it's quite common. Typically [X Window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is used for that.

But Windows GUI applications cannot be "tunneled" via SSH session to a local machine.